# A parser with Lepl

Tags: python, parsing, lepl

I want to parse a text file, for example, something like this:

```
div::
    class:yo-d
    text:example
    id:my-class
    h1:: Title
        href:http://www.example.com
    div::
        class:class1
        id:my-class2
```

It is similar to reStructuredText.
Every *tag* ends with `::` and can have some attributes `attr:value`.
I want to obtain something like this, a Python dictionary:

```
{'div': {'attrs': {'text': 'example', 'class': 'yo-d', 'id': 'my-class'},
         'sub': {'h1': {'content': 'Title', 'attrs': {'href': 'http://www.example.com'}},
                 'div': {'attrs': {'class': 'class1', 'id': 'my-class2'}},
                },
        }
}
```

After *sub* there are the indented tags, and if something follows a tag's `::` it goes in `'content'`.

I would use Lepl, but I don't even know where to start, any suggestions?

Thanks,
rubik

Comment: I would start with some basic tutorials: http://www.acooke.org/lepl/intro-1.html

Comment: Thank you! I've just started reading.

Comment: This looks a lot like JSON.  Lepl includes a JSON parser that was submitted by a user.  See https://groups.google.com/group/lepl/browse_thread/thread/bb9e082dacca8c8b and http://www.acooke.org/lepl/api/lepl.contrib.json-pysrc.html#Simple

Comment: But note that only works with Python 3, I think.  That's due to the way escaped text is handled.  But you may not need that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using Lepl is Pyparsing: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

I am currently using Pyparsing successfully, and if you name the results you can get out dictionaries of named results.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing